# C++ How to overwrite data in text file in c++?

Tags: c++, fstream, overwrite

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
string dataFile = "data.txt";
int counter;

int main()
{
    string input ="";
    fstream data;
    data.open(dataFile, ios::app | ios::out | ios::in );
    getline(data, input);
    if (input == "")//The file must be new
    {
        counter = 0;
    }else {
        counter = stoi(input);
    }

    /*
        Program does some stuff that increases the counter
        Right before program ends we update the file
    */
    data.clear();
    data << counter;
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

So this is just some example code. The first time you run the program the counter starts at 0, which is accurate. Let's say you get 10 points this run through of the game. Your counter will be 10 when the game ends, and it is stored into the file no problem. So let's reopen the application, you see the counter is 10, cool, and you gain 6 points this time. So in game the counter reads 16. Before the application closes 16 is written to data.txt.

Inside of the data.txt it reads 1016, which is not accurate!

How can I clear the text inside of data.txt right before I write my accurate counter information to the file?

I was reading elsewhere that you cannot clear contents of a file using fstream, is there a more efficient way to overwrite data in a file?

Thank you.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file into memory. Update the values. Rewrite the file.